# Windows Azure Website with a Startup task

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

I know that Azure Websites are made to be easy, not have role configs and such...but I was still wondering, is there ANY way to create a Startup Task when using a Website?

I'm asking because I would like to ease the deployment of an existing website through FTP or GIT (not recompiling the source and such), and then use Startup Task to deploy an additional IIS provider to GAC?

Kind regards,
Vladan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of "Shared Instance" deployment model, I don't think it's possible because your application is sharing the VM with many other tenants (applications). Thus you will not have permissions to access GAC. Not sure how this would work in case of "Reserved Instance" deployment model where the whole VM is at your disposal.

Comment: I don't think it is feasible in the Reserved Instances either. Although the VM is "at your disposal", it is still maintained by MSFT, you are not deploying the worker role code.

Answer (score 1):

Actuall it's possible. Have a look at: [Windows Azure Website with a Startup task using Webmatrix 3 or similar (without using Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863618/windows-azure-website-with-a-startup-task-using-webmatrix-3-or-similar-without)

However, you can't run it with elevated privileges.