# Installing software on a Windows Azure dedicated website

Tags: asp.net, azure, installation, clearscript

I would need to install some software (the VC++ 2012 redistributables) on a Windows Azure website. This is part of a troubleshooting procedure related to using ClearScript on a Windows Azure website. More information here: https://clearscript.codeplex.com/workitem/18

Coming back to the question... How can I install the software I need on my dedicated website instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to install software on a Azure Web Role then you can do it in 3 different ways as listed here:

https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/installing-third-party-software-on-windows-azure-%E2%80%93-what-are-the-options/

If you have an Azure Website (not a role) then you don't have full control of your VM, even if you have a dedicated instance. But there is a way I read that you can possibly install some DLL's, in your project at least, I don't think you will have access to many other folders (or any at all) on your instance.

[Windows Azure Website with a Startup task using Webmatrix 3 or similar (without using Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863618/windows-azure-website-with-a-startup-task-using-webmatrix-3-or-similar-without)